# Css full width question

Tags: css

I have generated css for a page i am building in Adobe Fireworks Cs5 and i am wondering how i can set the full width for my header and other divs.I will show the css code up to the header section.

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 62.5%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body * {
 font-size: 100%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-weight: normal;
}
p {
 margin-bottom: 1.1em;
 margin-top: 0;
}
#main p.lastNode {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
a:link img, a:visited img {
 border: none;
}
div.clearFloat {
 clear: both;
 font-size: 0;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0px;
}
li.clearFloat {
 clear: both;
}
ul.symbolList {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.AbsWrap {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.rowWrap {
 width: 100%;
}
#main {
 margin: 0 auto 0 0;
 width: 960px;
}
#Div {
    position:absolute;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 background-color: #333;
 width: 960px;
 margin-left:-480px;
    left:50%;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: 849px;
}
html > body #Div {
 height: auto;
 min-height: 850px;
}
#Div2 {
   /* This is the Header*/
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 background-color: #300;
 width: 960px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: 99px;
}
html > body #Div2 {
 height: auto;
 min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set the header element to 100% of the browser's width?

Comment: I tried width : 100% for the width and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block level elements, such as div, are always full width if they are not contained inside some other element or positioned otherwise. In your case, it looks as if you absolutely positioned some elements without setting a width. This may cause the div to collapse onto itself unless it has content. Also, if you use percent to set a width, always remember that it's a percent of the parent. Is the parent set to any unit size itself?

Answer (score 0):

Change display property in #Div2 to the following:

```
#Div2 {
...
 display: block;
...
}
```

This will make the header div (#Div2) the full width of the container div (both 960px wide).

I would change the the same property in #Div1 as well.