# FW generated css full width issue

Tags: css

i have recently generated css using Fireworks cs5 and i cannot seem to set my my header full width.I have been trying various solutions but none has worked very well so far.I need Div2 which is my header to be full width.

Here is the code.

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body * {
    font-size: 100%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#main p.lastNode {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
a:link img, a:visited img {
    border: none;
}
div.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
}
li.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
}
ul.symbolList {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.AbsWrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.rowWrap {
    width: 100%;
}
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
#Div {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 849px;
}
html > body #Div {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 850px;
}
#Div2 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #e8807d;
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 99px;
}
html > body #Div2 {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716171/css-full-width-question — Didn't you just ask this question yesterday and mark an answer as correct?

Comment: The thing is,it matters how you generate the css.Yesterday,i was using absolute positioning to somehow get the divs centered,but i had problems centering some images.I soon discovered i could actually center my page and i guess that is the source of my confusion.

Comment: I was using this before. #Div {
    position:absolute;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 background-color: #333;
 width: 960px;
 margin-left:-480px;
    left:50%;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: 799px;
}
html > body #Div {
 height: auto;
 min-height: 800px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float:left` and `display: inline` — that should do it. (And the `width` property, if that doesn't define what you mean by "full width".)

Comment: Thanks it worked; i was a little confused about the centering.